# Right aligning text in column header in Outloook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to right align text in a column header in a HTML table for email sent to outlook.

I try:

```
<style>
        TH.right{font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding:5px 6px; text-align:right;margin:0px}
</style>
<th class="right" align="right">My Column Header</th>
```

And it does not work for Outlook. Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried to use `th.right` instead of `TH.right`?

Comment: @Sven Bieder tried does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the CSS as inline - some email clients have trouble with this. It's good practice in my opinion to only do inline css for email clients and html emails.

So instead do this:

```
<th align="right" style="font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding:5px 6px; text-align:right;margin:0px;">My Column Header</th>
```

- not tested.